# Getting an exception as "A method was called at an unexpected time" when using share contract for sharing files in windows 8 metro app?

Tags: xaml, email, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to share files using share contract in my app :-

```
public async void SendingEmail(UtilityClass objselecteditem)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder tempFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile sampleFile = await 
        tempFolder.CreateFileAsync("StundentDetails.html",   
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, htmlBuilder.ToString());
        await RegisterForShare();                        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {    
    }
}
```

I am calling this RegisterForShare() in the above method :-

```
private async Task RegisterForShare()
{
    DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();       
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareStorageItemsHandler);            
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();

}

private async void ShareStorageItemsHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)          
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Student Confirmation Email";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "Student Details";



    // Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
    // we need to get the deferral first.
    DataRequestDeferral deferral =  request.GetDeferral();

    // Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
    try
    {
        StorageFolder tempFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile EmailFile = await tempFolder.GetFileAsync("StundentDetails.html");      
        List<IStorageItem> storageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
        storageItems.Add(EmailFile);
        request.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItems);


    }
    finally
    {
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

for the first time it is performing correctly , the share contracxt is being opened for me to share files but if i am trying to share it again (second time to share files ) it throws an exception saying "A method was called at an unexpected time", Please let me know if i am doing any wrong , pls correct me .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should not do "DataRequested +=" multiple times and you should not call ShowShareUI other than when the user touches the screen keyboard or mouse. Just guessing. You did not say which line throws the exception.

Comment: first of thanks the reply , dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareStorageItemsHandler);   is the line where it throws the exception while trying it second time.pls let me know what should i do  for that not call mutiple times thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareStorageItemsHandler);
```

with

```
dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= ShareStorageItemsHandler;
dataTransferManager.DataRequested += ShareStorageItemsHandler;
```